# Ping one parallels machine to another

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, ping, parallels

I have assigned both parallels network adapter to a bridged network.

**Control Machine**  10.171.102.162
**Host Machine**  10.171.102.161

I can not ping or ssh from the control to the host machine which is both parallel instances of ubuntu

**Logs**

```
parallels@parallels-vm:~$ ansible -m ping all
10.251.55.13 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 10.251.55.13 port 22: Connection refused\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
parallels@parallels-vm:~$ ^C
parallels@parallels-vm:~$ ping ^C
parallels@parallels-vm:~$ ping 10.251.55.13 
PING 10.251.55.13 (10.251.55.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

ifconfig from control machine

```
parallels@parallels-vm:~$ ifconfig
enp0s5    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:42:9a:09:73  
          inet addr:**10.171.102.162**  Bcast:10.171.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c1e2:6bd6:234b:1ea6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6650 errors:0 dropped:339 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:449 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:745003 (745.0 KB)  TX bytes:43829 (43.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:196 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:196 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14551 (14.5 KB)  TX bytes:14551 (14.5 KB)
```

ifconfig from host machine

```
enp0s5    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:42:b6:2e:e6  
          inet addr:10.171.102.161  Bcast:10.171.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5fa6:2a6b:a1a9:fbbf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:963997 errors:0 dropped:40266 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:220780 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:464186542 (464.1 MB)  TX bytes:21117153 (21.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:37873 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37873 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2971041 (2.9 MB)  TX bytes:2971041 (2.9 MB)
```

Comment: ahhh solved it...After restarting the machines in the same Bridged network adapter. Will post after a day with pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Restart** the machines or **restart** the network cards to get the new ip address.